# How to toggle or pause setInterval in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am learning java Script and i am trying to create clock which should be "when I  click the button, the time Should stop changing and the button Should change from “Stop time” to “Start time” & when I click the button again, the time should begin changing and the button should change from “Start time” to “Stop time”. See my codes and tell me which codes or function i need to add and where to add... I am newbie in it so i will appreciate your help..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
</body>
</html>
```

//---Script Here---

```
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
var d = new Date();
var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
clearInterval(myVar);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. Take some time to read more about the site in the [help] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**

```js
let currentTime = new Date();
let status = true;
let interval = 1; // in seconds
let dateFormat = { hour: 'numeric', minute:'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: true };

let clock = document.querySelector('#demo');
    clock.innerHTML = currentTime.toLocaleString('en-US', dateFormat);

let timer = setInterval(
    function () {
        currentTime.setSeconds(currentTime.getSeconds() + interval);
        clock.innerHTML = currentTime.toLocaleString('en-US', dateFormat);
    }, interval * 1000
);

let button = document.querySelector('#button');
    button.addEventListener('click', onClick);

function onClick() {
    if (!status) {
        button.innerHTML = 'Stop timer';

        timer = setInterval(
            function () {
                currentTime.setSeconds(currentTime.getSeconds() + interval);
                clock.innerHTML = currentTime.toLocaleString('en-US', dateFormat);
            }, interval * 1000
        );

        return;
    }

    if (status) {
        button.innerHTML = 'Start timer';
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    status = !status;
}
```

```html
<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button id="button">Stop time</button>
```

Comment: Can u make it like when we run it should already display time running with Stop button and when i press stop button then time get stop and button changes to start button. In short. Time is not displaying during running but after press button it is displaying

Comment: sure, just a min

Comment: Every thing perfect... just need Time format like 6:02:45 AM

Comment: I think it will be a good practice to you to find an answer by yourself ;) if not i'll post an answer in 1 hour

Comment: Yes I am trying. Infact. I learn HTML that is interesting and easy but i am facing problems in java although it is also interesting

Comment: So it will be your task ;) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I get the required result and i learn a today what i deserve.

Comment: You are welcome. But first of all try to solve any issue by yourself next time

Comment: @EngrBilawalMalik In the future add your own answer rather than radically editing the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: ok bro. i am new on this site that's why such blunder happened

Comment: I'd like to add here for anyone interested that the `return` statement inside the `onClick` function should be removed. When you've inverted `status` once, the code below the first `if-statement` becomes unreachable because `status` will never become `true` again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a little trick to toggle the function here you are:

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
      myTimer()
}, 1000);
var isPaused = false;

function myTimer() {
      var d = new Date();
      var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function toggleFunction() {
      if (isPaused) {
            myVar = setInterval(function () {
                  myTimer()
            }, 1000);
            isPaused = false;
      } else {
            clearInterval(myVar);
            isPaused = true;
      }
}
```

```html
<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="toggleFunction()">Toggle time</button>
```

Comment: But it's not creating loop. its works only one time and Also button not changing to stop to start..???

Answer (score 0):

```js
let time = document.getElementById("time");
let stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");

let timeCount = 0,
  currentTimeout;

function play() {
  stopButton.hidden = false;
  clearInterval(currentTimeout);
  currentTimeout = setInterval(() => {
    timeCount++;
    const min = String(Math.trunc(timeCount / 60)).padStart(2, 0);
    const sec = String(Math.trunc(timeCount % 60)).padStart(2, 0);
    time.innerHTML = `${min} : ${sec}`;
  }, 1000);
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(currentTimeout);
}

function stop() {
  stopButton.hidden = true;
  pause();
  timeCount = 0;
  time.innerHTML = `00 : 00`;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="time">00 : 00</h1>
  <br />
  <div>
    <button onclick="play()">play</button>
    <button onclick="pause()">pause</button>
    <button onclick="stop()" id="stop" hidden>Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```